# Calling salesforce API using java application returns 301

Tags: rest-api, api, salesforce1-app, java

I tested the following code and is working perfectly on sandbox and returning the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Successful login
  instance URL: https://XXXX.salesforce.com
  access token/session ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Whenever I set the configuration to production and try to run the same code I get the following:

```
Error authenticating to Force.com: 301
```

I double checked the username, password and everything but it still fails.

Below is my java code:

I run it as a jar same for sandbox and production while changing the configuration file which has the variables USERNAME, PASSWORD, LOGINURL, etc.

```
void getInstanceAndAccessToken() {

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Assemble the login request URL
        String loginURL = LOGINURL + GRANTSERVICE + "&client_id=" + CLIENTID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET
                + "&username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD;

        // Login requests must be POSTs
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            // Execute the login POST request
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpException) {
            cpException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

        // verify response is HTTP OK
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: " + statusCode);
            // Error is in EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
            return;
        }

        String getResult = null;
        try {
            getResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String loginAccessToken = null;
        String loginInstanceUrl = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getResult).nextValue();
            loginAccessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
            loginInstanceUrl = jsonObject.getString("instance_url");
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
            jsonException.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Successful login");
        System.out.println("  instance URL: " + loginInstanceUrl);
        System.out.println("  access token/session ID: " + loginAccessToken);

        // release connection
        httpPost.releaseConnection();
}
```

Comment: Is your client id/secret still from sandbox or it points to production?

Comment: 301 is a redirect, not an error. Please make sure you are going to the correct LOGINURL when logging in. If a redirect occurs, that means you went to the wrong URL. Also, you might want to debug the response value in order to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your connected app is set up in Production, its correctly provisioned and permissioned and client_id/client_secret values are correct.
2. Password should contain the security token
3. Login URL and grant_type parameter are correct.

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm), they spell this out. If your authentication use case is service-to-service (no user interaction), you should take a look at [JWT Bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).